# How to import excel file that attached in my google account into spreadsheet automatically?

Tags: excel, import, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a script that import excel file that attached in my google account into spreadsheet automatically. 
I want to email a excel file with a link to somebody.Then when he/she click on link, excel file import into spreadsheet automatically. How to do this?

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You click on your options in google drive and select automatically import to google format.

Pretty simple.